# Is it a good / working practice to use Firebase's documentReference.get(GetOptions(source: cache)) in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My issue was, that with the **default GetOptions** (omitting the parameter), a request like the following **could load seconds if not minutes** if the client is **offline**:

```
    await docRef.get()...
```

If I **check if the client is offline** and in this case purposefully **change the Source to Source.cache**, I have performance that is at least as good, if not better, than if the client was online.

```
    Source _source = Source.serverAndCache;

    try {
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
       if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
          _source = Source.serverAndCache;
       } 
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      _source = Source.cache;
    }
```

and then use this variable in the following way:

```
   docRef.get(GetOptions(source: _source))
   .then(...
```

This code works perfectly for me now, but I am not sure, if there are **any cases** in which using the **code like this could raise issues**.

Also it seems like a lot of **boilerplate** code (I refactored it into a function so I can use it in any Database methods but still...)

If there are no issues with this, why wouldn't this be the Firebase **default**, since after trying the server for an **unpredictably long time it switches to cache** anyways.